# PHP form validation submitting blank data

Tags: php, validation, authentication

I am trying to create a page to allow users to edit their details using PHP, which validates the content before being submitted.
I want to allow users to update their username, first and second name and email address.

The validation consists of:

```
<?php
if(preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]{3,}$/", $_POST["username"]) == 0)
$error_username = '<li>Usernames may contain only digits, upper and lower case letters and underscores</li>';

if(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]+$/", $_POST["fname"]) == 0)
$error_fname = '<li>First Name may contain upper and lower case letters</li>';

if(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]+$/", $_POST["sname"]) == 0)
$error_sname = '<li>Second Name may contain upper and lower case letters</li>';

if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]\w+(\.\w+)*\@\w+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/", $_POST["email"]) == 0)
$error_email = '<li>Email Addresses must have a valid email address format</li>';

else header("Location: edit.php");  
?>
```

And to display the errors:

```
<ul>
<?php  if(isset($error_username)) echo $error_username; ?>
<?php  if(isset($error_fname)) echo $error_fname; ?>
<?php  if(isset($error_sname)) echo $error_sname; ?>
<?php  if(isset($error_email)) echo $error_email; ?>
</ul>
```

The form that I have is:

```
<form name="edit_account" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<input class="form_field" name="username" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST["username"]; ?>" placeholder="Username">
<input class="form_field" name="fname" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>" placeholder="First Name">
<input class="form_field" name="sname" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST["sname"]; ?>" placeholder="Second Name">
<input class="form_field" name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>" placeholder="Email Address">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update Account">
</form>
```

Providing that all requirements of the validation are met, the user is taken to edit.php and then redirected to a success page:

```
<?php
$sql = $mysqli; 
$id = htmlentities($_SESSION['user_id']); 

$username = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$fname = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['fname']); 
$sname = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['sname']);  
$email = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$query = ("
UPDATE users 
SET 
username='$username', 
fname='$fname', 
sname='$sname',
email='$email' 
WHERE id='$id'") ; 


$sql->query($query) or die($query.'<br />'.$sql->error); 
header ('Location: success.php');  
?>
```

When I attempt to run this code, the updating fields are submitted into the database as blanks - However, without the validation, the users submitted details are successfully entered.

Can someone please point out what is causing the form to submit as a blank. Thanks.

Comment: your validation will fail many legitimate names and email addresses

Comment: Is `session_start();` loaded somewhere? Since you're using sessions. If not, **do**.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, it is at the top of the document

Comment: I think you should do any validation of inputs on the client side, not serverside

Comment: @Chancho It should be done on both.  Client side might not support HTML5 validation, or might have JS disabled.  At that point it has to be done on the server side or it won't get done at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're posting them to the validation page, but losing them when you redirect to the `edit.php` page.  Store the information in session variables before going to `edit.php`, like this:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST["username"];
// other variables also
```

On the `edit.php`, instead of pulling from `$_POST`, pull from `$_SESSION`.

**Side Notes**

Don't forget `session_start()` at the top of each page.  Also, you should look into [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) when using user input.

Comment: *"mysql_* functions are deprecated"* -- ??? OP is using `mysqli`. You can't use `real_escape_string` with `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: You're right, editing now.  Any time I see non-prepared statements I just assume mysql.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are redirecting to edit.php (which contains database insertion code) from the validation script. The issue is that the $_POST variable is reset when you redirect.

I would `include('path/to/edit.php')` the edit.php script rather than redirect to it. If that isn't possible, I would save the $_POST data in a $_SESSION variable.

Hope this helps